# Dynamically loaded form, nested in a table doesn't retrieve values for inputs

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post

I have been researching over the stackoverflow answers but was unable to find the one that would help me fix the issue.

I have a form that is loaded via ajax, where inputs are nested inside a table. I am trying to post that data into DB, but the values of inputs are always read as empty.

HTML form :

```
    <form method="POST" action="index.php" id="clientsubmitform">
   <table class="table table-responsive col-md-6 col-lg-6 form-group">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Lead Type</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="clientid[]" value="26" form="clientsubmitform"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="clientfirstname" name="clientfirstname[]" value="Robert" form="clientsubmitform" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="clientlastname" name="clientlastname[]" value="DeNiro" form="clientsubmitform" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="clientphonenumber" name="clientphonenumber[]" value="0987654321" form="clientsubmitform" readonly></td>
            <td id="statustd">
               <select id="status" name="statusselect[]" form="clientsubmitform">
                  <option> </option>
                  <option value="1" class="status">Answered</option>
                  <option value="2" class="status">No Answer</option>
                  <option value="3" class="status">Busy</option>
                  <option value="4" class="status">Call Back</option>
                  <option value="5" class="status">Wrong Number</option>
                  <option value="6" class="status">Lead</option>
                  <option value="7" class="status">Indian</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td id="islead" style="display: none;">
               <select class="isleadgrade" name="isleadselect[]" form="clientsubmitform">
                  <option>Lead Type</option>
                  <option value="1">Cold  Lead</option>
                  <option value="2">Warm Lead</option>
                  <option value="3">Hot Lead!</option>
               </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <br><input type="button" class="btn btn-task col-md-8 col-lg-8 offset-lg-1 offset-md-1" id="clientsubmit" name="clientsubmit" value="SUBMIT" form="clientsubmitform">
</form>
```

PHP function :

```
global $db;
    global $data;
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") :
    $userid = $_SESSION['login_user_id'];
    $clientid = isset($_POST['clientid']) != '' ? $_POST['clientid'] : array();
    for($i = 0; $i <= count($clientid); $i++) {
        $status = isset($_POST['statusselect']) != '' ? $_POST['statusselect'][$i] : NULL;
        $leadtype = isset($_POST['isleadselect']) != '' ? $_POST['isleadselect'][$i] : NULL;
        $clientid = isset($_POST['clientid']) != '' ? $_POST['clientid'][$i] : NULL;
        $query = "UPDATE clients SET status = '$status', leadtype = '$leadtype' WHERE id = '$clientid' AND agent_assigned = '$userid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        return true;
    }
    endif;
```

The data from the PHP function gets passed to an ajax_response function which triggers the success or fail. The POST is successful, however the values remain empty.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Hi. What values are empty? In DB or in POST? I've replicated your code and POST seems to be ok - array is populated correctly. So, my guess that DB query isn't performed correctly. Please, enable error_reporting for PHP script and check possible errors. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Anton

I found that the issue was hiding in my JS which was used to pass information with ajax. I sorted it out by using jquery form plugin .ajaxForm